# How can I dynamically change name of component reference <dropdown-component> at the run time globally in angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

In my current application, there is a component called "dropdown-component" which is used across the application, I have to use "custom-dropdown-component" instead of "dropdown-component". I will not be able to do the changes to every file where ever its called as there is some specific business requirement. These changes should be reflected at the time of render. Kindly help with this

**Current code**

```
<dropdown-component></dropdown-component>
```

**Expected to change at the runtime**

```
<custom-dropdown-component></custom-dropdown-component>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the component at runtime without major changes to the whole code.

Probably the simplest solution would be to do a search/replace or you can create the `custom-dropdown-component` but call it `dropdown-component` instead, then you you have to import the Custom Module but this is also kind tricky and not a nice solution